# Как найти все возможные варианты перестановок цифр заданного числа?

Tags: c++, комбинаторика

С помощью какого алгоритма можно перебрать все n! возможные варианты перестановок цифр заданного числа?

P.S.
Под **перестановками** подразумевается полное множество **размещений без повторений** при n = k , где

- n - размер набора символов;
- k - число позиций, в которых происходят перестановки символов.

Comment: каких еще перестановок?

Comment: Был недавно почти такой же вопрос, только про буквы

ABCDE -> AB AC AD AE ABC ABD ...

IMHO автор по этому поводу спрашивал, как узнать, какие биты в числе установлены.

Вот [нашел](http://hashcode.ru/questions/257698) (там даже есть 2 программки).

Comment: как-то не очень хочется гадать. Тем более, скорее всего это очередной хреновый студент со своей лабораторной

Comment: @bananya, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Могу посоветовать next_permutation

Comment: @dzhioev: не всё так просто: цифры могут повторяться, и содержать нули (которым нельзя попадать на первое место). Например, случай числа 1122, перестановки (1<->3)(2<->4) и (1<->4)(2<->3) дают 2211. То есть придётся запоминать все промежуточные результаты, что есть не айс.

Answer (score 2):

Да это можно посчитать и без перебора.

Имея алфавит ABCDE получаем 5^1+5^2+5^3+5^4+5^5
5^1 - A-Z
5^2 - AA - EE
и т.д.
т.е. размер алфавита в степени равной количеству символов

Comment: Угу, а теперь учтите, что нули не могут находиться на начальной позиции, а также повторяющиеся цифры, которые не дают нового варианта, если их переставить.

Answer (score 1):

[Тасование Фишера–Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0)

Цитата: "Современная версия алгоритма очень эффективна и требует время, пропорциональное числу элементов множества, и не требует дополнительного пространства."